# A basic question in the proof of Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $P$ be the set of all subsets of $X$. Now, define a partial order $\leq$ on $P$ such that $A \leq B$ iff $A$ is a subset of $B$. Now, take any chain $C$ from $P$. Now, we can find an upper bound of $C$ as $\cup_{B \in C}B$ in $P$. Now, I think this upper bound, indeed, lies in $C$ because $C$  is a chain (although it does not matter in the proof). Is this correct ?

Answer (score 3):

To apply Zorn's lemma, the upper bound needs to lie in the partially ordered set, not in the chain.  In this case, the partially ordered set is the power set of $X$, and the upper bound $\cup_{B\in C}B$ is a subset of $X$.

For clarity, here is the statement of Zorn's lemma:

> If a partially ordered set $P$ has the property that every chain has an upper bound **in $\mathbf{P}$**, then the set $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

In the case of $P=\mathcal{P}(X)$ ordered by inclusion, there is a unique maximal element, which is $X$.

Answer (score 1):

No, chains in $P$ don't necessarily contain their own upper bounds. If $X$ is an infinite set, consider a chain of finite sets of the form $\emptyset\subset\{x_1\}\subset\{x_1,x_2\}\subset\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\subset\cdots$.